# Doubt about a spanning set solution.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have given a set $N = \{0, 1, x, 2x^2, 3x^3, 4x^4, 5x^5\}$. I know that this set is linearly dependent, because it contains the $0$ polynomial.
That is why it can not be a basis for $R_5[x]$  (polynomials with real coefficients of at most 5-th degree). But I can not understand the quick solution that it is a spanning set for $R_5[x]$. I know that if we check for scalars we can always find them for any polynomial in $R_5[x]$.

But I do not understand this solution:
$\{1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5\} ⊂ Span (N)$, so $R_5[x]$ $\leq$ $Span (N)$. So, $N$ is a spanning set for $R_5[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

The first inclusion holds because $$x^2=\frac 12\cdot 2x^2
=0.\color{blue}{0} +0.\color{blue}{1} +0.\color{blue}{x} +\frac 12 \color{blue}{2x^2} +0.(\color{blue}{3x^3} )+0.(\color{blue}{4x^4} )+0.(\color{blue}{5x^5} ),$$
which appears to be a linear combination of elements of $N=\{ \color{blue}{0,1,x,2x^2,3x^3,4x^4,5x^5}\},$ hence $x^2\in\operatorname{Span}(N)$. 
Similarly, $x^3\in \operatorname{Span}(N)$.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that is ok for me. But how do we know that $R_5[x] $$\leq$$ Span(N)$ and not the opposite, which is more logical for me? Is it for the reason that the vector space containing the set $N$ has dimension 7, and hence $R_5[x]$ can only be a subspace of it? I don't get the last two implications, by which theorem we can conclude that?

Comment: Since $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5\}\subset \operatorname{Span}(N)$ and the right hand side is a vector space, the vector space generated by the left hand side is contained in $\operatorname{Span}(N)$. Since $\operatorname{Span}\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5\}=\mathbb R_5[x]$, we conclude that $\mathbb R_5[x]\subset \operatorname{Span}(N)$.